# How to remove current location indicator (the blue circle) and show only map's control on that location

Tags: angular, google-maps, maps, nativescript

I want to remove current location indicator (the blue circle)  when using google maps in Nativescript.

I try this code, but this remove map's control. I want only to remove current location indicator (the blue circle).

```
onCameraMove(args) {
    console.log('args', args)
      if(args) {
        this.gMap = args.object.gMap;
        this.gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        this.gMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);          
    }
    console.log("Camera moving: " + JSON.stringify(args.camera));
}
```

html

```
 <MapView class="map" (cameraChanged)="onCameraMove($event)"></MapView>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to make sense. The job of location button is to focus the current location, the blue indicator is used to highlight current location?

Comment: Remove both via the native API you have used and the create your own custom button.